# Typescript: generic functional type/interface for arrow function

Tags: typescript, generics, types, arrow-functions, typescript-generics

Ok, I have the following scenario:

```
type IHashFn = (arg: string) => number;
const hash: IHashFn = (arg) => {
  return 42;
}
```

So far, so good. Now I want the function to be generic.

```
const hash: <T> (arg: T) => number = (arg) => {
  return 42;
}
```

That works. But this doesn't:

```
type IHashFn<T> = (arg: T) => number;
const hash: <T> IHashFn<T> = (arg) => {
  return 42;
}
```

I found no way to calm down the TS compiler. Using interfaces instead of type aliases doesn't work either.

Note: I dont't want `hash` to be an implementation for `IHashFn<string>` but generic as well.

Is there a way to declare generic function types or interfaces in TypeScript at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't really doing anything with your generic parameter.

But it sounds like you want a generic function, not a generic type alias. So leave it on the function, and off of the type alias.

```
type IHashFn = <T>(arg: T) => number;

const hash: IHashFn = (arg) => {
  return 42;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use the built-in Typescript utilities `Parameters` and `ResultType`.

For your case:

```
type IHashFn<T> = (arg: T) => number;
const hash: <T> (...args: Parameters<IHashFn<T>>) => ResultType<IHashFn<T>> = (arg) => {
  return 42;
}
```

---

There might be a cleaner way with the keyword `infer` used directly, but I could not find it. Maybe someone else can add it here.

I had the same question and it was impossible to find a solution for me, I had to learn about the existence of these utilities and figure it out by myself.

In my case, I wanted to take advantage of the existing `React.FunctionComponent` (or `React.FC`) type alias, while using a generic.

List of utility types: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html

More info on infer: https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-infer-typescript/

Comment: Oof, one year ago. I remember that I was playing with React.FC for a generic `createRoute` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `IHashFn<any>`. This will be usable where `IHashFn<string>` is expected too.

If you truly want it to still be a generic function type, you could do something like this:

```
type IHashFn<T = any> = <U extends T>(arg: U) => number;
```