# Generic function parameters not compatible?

Tags: typescript

```
type Func =  <T>(funcParams?: T) => void;
type Foo = {
    foofoo:any
}
const someOtherFunc = (foo: Foo)=>{console.log(foo.foofoo);};
const funcImpl : Func = (foo?:Foo) => {
//use Foo specific implementation
foo && someOtherFunc(foo);
};
```

This gives error that type Foo and T are incompatible. What am I doing wrong here?

I think this is related: [Typescript: generic functional type/interface for arrow function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61376309/typescript-generic-functional-type-interface-for-arrow-function).
But couldn't understand. The answer is kind of weird according to me. I mean it's kind of obvious I would want to use a type specific implementation.

Comment: It does not give the error that "`Foo` and `T` are incompatible".  You should include the actual error message, which, among other things says `Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Foo'.`  The problem is your function's parameter must be *optional* to be a valid `Func<Foo>`, as shown [here in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wezDEN).  This feels almost like a typo; pattern matching would turn  `(funcParams?: T) =>` into `(funcParams?: Foo) => ` and that would work.  Is there a reason you want the parameter to be required?

Comment: @jcalz. Thanks a lot for your reply.
I think I didn't write it correctly. I was creating a short reproducible code from my original code. The first code snippet is not applicable. The second one is. Let me update and delete the first one. (you might not be able to refer to first code snippet I wrote as I might have deleted it)

Comment: Yes. in the implementation I want to call a function which uses Foo type as param.

Answer (score 1):

So I can spot two issues with the code you have provided.

1. You have defined Func wrongly. The Generic comes on the left-hand side, [unless you want a generic function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61376469/12340367).
2. How you want to use that type. You will also need to pass the type as an argument when you want to use a generic.

```
type Func<T> = (funcParams?: T) => void; // changed this line
type Foo = {
    foofoo: string
}
const funcImpl: Func<Foo> = (foo) => { // changed this line
  if (!foo) {
    return;
  }
  const test = foo.foofoo // test will be typed as string
}
```

I am by no means an expert but how I understand it, if you define it on the right-hand side would look more like this:

```
type Func =  <T>(funcParams: T) => T;

const someOtherFunc: Func = (foo) => {
  return foo
};


const test = someOtherFunc('test') // inferred from arg
const testNumber = someOtherFunc(50) // inferred from arg
const testString = someOtherFunc<string>(50) // this will error out
```

What you essentially define there is in case you want to pass the type dynamically when you actually call the function. So the Function is generic and not the Type, hence it will be inferred when you actually call the function.

If you define the generic on the left-hand side, TS expects the argument when you want to use the type, because the type is generic.

Comment: Can you tell what's the difference when defining it on the left side to defining on right side for a function?

Comment: @AdityaKumar I edited my answer. Hopefully this makes sense

Comment: @AdityaKumar would you accept my answer if this did the trick for you?